# How to put a map infowindow using html and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, google-maps, infowindow

Hello I am newbie to html and angularjs, I a making a dmeo on google maps markers,I successfully got the marker on map,but now I want to put an infowindow on that marker ,I have searched a to many things but not fit in my scenario,SO could anyone help me how to put an infowindow on map marker,my code is as below.
**html**

```
<div class="mapclass">

      <ons-row class="app-map">   
        <ons-col> 
          <map  center="[{{lat}}, {{lng}}]">
            <marker  ng-model 
                position="[{{lat}}, {{lng}}]"
                title= "{{tittle}}"
                animation="Animation.BOUNCE" 
                visible="true" ></marker>
          </map> 
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
     </div>
```

**js**

```
 app.controller('listingdetailController', function ($http, $scope, $compile, $filter, $sce,$timeout) {

        var SearchTxt = 'cay';
        var url = encodeURI("http://www.yahoo.com");
         var page = gallery.getCurrentPage();
         var FkCategory = page.options.params;
         var lat='';
         var lng = '';
         var img = '';
           var share = '';
         var title = '';
          var phone = '';
         var web  = '';
         var email = '';
         var about='';
         var help='';
         var Info='';
         var Service='';
          $timeout(callAtTimeout, 1000);


          function callAtTimeout() {
             console.log("Timeout occurred");


           share = $scope.share;
//         console.log("===iside details======"+FkCategory);
         $scope.img = "http://caymanafterwork.netcluesdemo.com/cache/business/images/337_224/papagallo1438959641.jpg";

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:  API_HOST+'/webservice/listingdetail',
            headers:
                    {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'caymanauth': caymanauth
                    },
            data: "&Catid=" + FkCategory + "&SearchTxt=" + SearchTxt,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }).success(function (data)
        {
            var i;
            var Content = ' ';
            for (i = 0; i<data['Details'].length; i++)
            {
                lat =  + data['Details'][i]['varLatitude'];
                lng =  + data['Details'][i]['varLongitude'];
                img =  data['Details'][i]['varCompanyLogo'];
                title = data['Details'][i]['varTitle'];

                about= data['Details'][i]['varDescBusiness'];
                help= data['Details'][i]['varMetaDescription'];
                Info= data['Details'][i]['varSpecials'];
                Service= data['Details'][i]['varDescBusiness'];
                 share = data['Details'][i]['varFacebookLink'];

              $scope.about = about;  
              $scope.help = help; 
              $scope.Info = Info; 
              $scope.Service = Service; 
            $scope.title = title;
            $scope.photo = ("http://caymanafterwork.netcluesdemo.com/cache/business/images/337_224/"+img);
            $scope.lat = lat;
            $scope.lng= lng;
            $scope.geo = {  lat: lat, lng: lng };
            $scope.phone= data['Details'][i]['varPhone'];
                $scope.web=  data['Details'][i]['varWebsiteLink'];
                $scope.email= data['Details'][i]['varBusinessEmail'];
            phone =   $scope.phone;
            web  = $scope.web;
            email = $scope.email;
            share = $scope.share;



                if (Content === ' ')
                {
                    Content =                     
     '<ons-list class="list ons-list-inner" style="border-top: none;">' +

           '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">'+
            '<ons-row class="detail-row row ons-row-inner">'+
              '<ons-col width="30px" style="flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px; -moz-box-flex: 0;" class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                  '<ons-icon fixed-width="true" icon="fa-map-marker" class="ons-icon fa-map-marker fa fa-lg">'+'</ons-icon>'+
              '</ons-col>'+
              '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                 '<div class="desc">'+ data['Details'][i]['varCityName']+'</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+              
            '</ons-row>'+
          '</ons-list-item>'+

          '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">'+
            '<ons-row class="detail-row row ons-row-inner">'+
              '<ons-col width="30px" style="flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px; -moz-box-flex: 0;" class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                '<ons-icon fixed-width="true" icon="ion-home" class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-home fa-lg"></ons-icon>'+              
              '</ons-col>'+
              '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                '<div class="desc">'+ data['Details'][i]['varPhysicalAddress'] + '</div>'+
              '</ons-col> '+             
            '</ons-row>'+
          '</ons-list-item>'+     

          '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">'+
            '<ons-row class="detail-row row ons-row-inner">'+
              '<ons-col width="30px" style="flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px; -moz-box-flex: 0;" class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                '<ons-icon fixed-width="true" icon="ion-soup-can" class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-soup-can fa-lg">'+
                '</ons-icon>'+              
              '</ons-col>'+
              '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                '<div class="desc">' + data['Details'][i]['varPOBOXAddress']+'</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+              
            '</ons-row>'+
          '</ons-list-item>'+
             '</ons-list>'+

             '<div class=caw-botton>'+
            '<ons-row class="row ons-row-inner">'+ 

                '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("book-page.html");>'+
                 '<div style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(221,221,221,0.6); padding: 12px 0; background: #0ad046; color: #FFF;">'+
                   '<i class="ion-compose">'+'</i>Book Now</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+

               '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("review.html");>'+
                   '<div style="padding: 12px 0; background: #cccccc; color: #FFF;">'+
                  '<i class="ion-edit">'+
                  '</i>Write a Review</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+

               '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("email-friend.html");>'+
                   '<div style="padding: 12px 0; background: #0ad046; color: #FFF;">'+
                  '<i class="ion-ios-email">'+
                  '</i>Email-friend</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+

             '</ons-row>'+
                ' </div>';

                }

                else
                {

   '<ons-list class="list ons-list-inner" style="border-top: none;">' +

           '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">'+
            '<ons-row class="detail-row row ons-row-inner">'+
              '<ons-col width="30px" style="flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px; -moz-box-flex: 0;" class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                  '<ons-icon fixed-width="true" icon="fa-map-marker" class="ons-icon fa-map-marker fa fa-lg">'+'</ons-icon>'+
              '</ons-col>'+
              '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                 '<div class="desc">'+ data['Details'][i]['varCityName']+'</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+              
            '</ons-row>'+
          '</ons-list-item>'+

          '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">'+
            '<ons-row class="detail-row row ons-row-inner">'+
              '<ons-col width="30px" style="flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px; -moz-box-flex: 0;" class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                '<ons-icon fixed-width="true" icon="ion-home" class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-home fa-lg"></ons-icon>'+              
              '</ons-col>'+
              '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                '<div class="desc">'+ data['Details'][i]['varPhysicalAddress'] + '</div>'+
              '</ons-col> '+             
            '</ons-row>'+
          '</ons-list-item>'+     

          '<ons-list-item class="list__item ons-list-item-inner">'+
            '<ons-row class="detail-row row ons-row-inner">'+
              '<ons-col width="30px" style="flex: 0 0 30px; max-width: 30px; -moz-box-flex: 0;" class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                '<ons-icon fixed-width="true" icon="ion-soup-can" class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-soup-can fa-lg">'+
                '</ons-icon>'+              
              '</ons-col>'+
              '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner">'+
                '<div class="desc">' + data['Details'][i]['varPOBOXAddress']+'</div>'+
              '</ons-col>'+              
            '</ons-row>'+
          '</ons-list-item>'+
             '</ons-list>'+

             '<div class=caw-botton>'+
            '<ons-row class="row ons-row-inner">'+ 
                '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("book-page.html");>'+
                 '<div style="border-right: 1px solid rgba(221,221,221,0.6); padding: 12px 0; background: #0ad046; color: #FFF;">'+
                   '<i class="ion-compose">'+'</i>Book Now</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+
               '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("review.html");>'+
                   '<div style="padding: 12px 0; background: #cccccc; color: #FFF;">'+
                  '<i class="ion-edit">'+
                  '</i>Write a Review</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+

               '<ons-col class="col ons-col-inner" onclick=gallery.pushPage("email-friend.html");>'+
                   '<div style="padding: 12px 0; background: #0ad046; color: #FFF;">'+
                  '<i class="ion-ios-email">'+
                  '</i>Email-friend</div>'+
               '</ons-col>'+

             '</ons-row>'+
                ' </div>';
                      }
            }

           $scope.show1 = true;
            $scope.show1 = function(){

                $scope.show2 = false;
                 $scope.show3 = false;
                  $scope.show4 = false;
            };
               $scope.show2 = true;
            $scope.show2 = function(){

                $scope.show1 = false;
                 $scope.show3 = false;
                  $scope.show4 = false;
            };
             $scope.show3 = true;
            $scope.show3 = function(){

                $scope.show1 = false;
                 $scope.show2 = false;
                  $scope.show4 = false;
            };
             $scope.show4 = true;
              $scope.show4 = function(){

                $scope.show1 = false;
                 $scope.show2 = false;
                  $scope.show3 = false;
            };



      $scope.openChildWindow = function () {

  window.open( web, '_blank', 'location=yes');
};
            $scope.snippet = Content;

        }).error(function ()
        {
            alert("error");
        });

         $scope.sendEmail = function(subject, body){
        var link = "mailto:"+ email
                 + "&subject=New email " + escape(subject);
                 + "&body=" + escape(body); 

        window.location.href = link;
     };

      $scope.call = function ()
        {
            parent.location.href = "tel:"+phone;
        };

        $scope.openWebsite = function ()
        {
            window.open( web, '_blank', 'location=yes');
        };


      $scope.openSocialSharing = function ()
        {
            window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message,image and link', null, 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png', 'http://www.google.com');

            };

        $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function ()
        {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
        };
    }
    });
```

Comment: i think you have to post you angular js model since it is more related to it...

Comment: @aSeptik-sure pls see my edits

Comment: where are the markers?

Comment: @aSeptik-in html <marker> tag..!

Comment: see my answer and let me knwo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/how-to-put-a-map-infowindow-using-html-and-angularjs

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div ng-controller="EventSimpleCtrl">
        <map zoom="4" center="-25.363882, 131.044922">
            <marker position="-25.363882, 131.044922" on-click="click()" title="Click to zoom"></marker>
        </map>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('EventSimpleCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var marker, map;
    $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(evt, evtMap) {
        map = evtMap;
        marker = map.markers[0];
        // this one is if you want to keep an hardcoded <info-window>
        // var infoWindow = map.infoWindows[0];
    });
    $scope.click = function(event) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infoWindow.setContent('Testing');
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
}]);
</script>
```

**NOTE:**

i guess you are using this library http://ngmap.github.io, so, from the [DOCs](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/tree/master/build/docs) it say you can have [info-windows](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/build/docs/info-window.html) in 2 ways, one is to put the  tag direcly into the `<map>` tag like this:

```
<info-window id="foo" position="current-location" visible="true"> Some Text Here </info-window>
```

and access it like this

```
...
function($scope, $timeout) {
        var marker, map, infoWindow;
        $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(evt, evtMap) {
            map = evtMap;
            marker = map.markers[0];
            // get the info-window by it's id foo
            infoWindow = map.infoWindows['foo'];
        });
       ...
```

after you got it you can use it like you will do with normal **GMAP API V3**

> - Any InfoWindow **[options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#InfoWindowOptions)**
> - Any InfoWindow **[events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)**

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle shows google maps and markers and on click of markers it will show infowindow:

```
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
         <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pc7Uu/854/

Comment: hello,its working demo i have gone thru it,but i dont have idea how to put this in my code,as i have put code to showing marker and map in my html..!!

Comment: pls see this and help me to save